# What Makes Xcode Command-Click (code indexing) Stop Working?

Tags: xcode, indexing

My Xcode project has been working fine with the ability to command-click on elements in code (struct type, method call, prototype, enum, etc) and jump to the definition.

Because of dust bunnies, I duplicate the entire project folder. I then get in and clean things up a little. Code builds as expected but then I discover that none of the command click indexes seem to be functional. Command-click on anything (including include files) just beeps at me.

I open the original project in the original project folder and command-click works to find definitions. I copy the old Xcode project file over to the new project folder (replacing the new one) and then in the old project command-click no longer works. It's as if indexing breaks and the only change is where the project is located.

All the files in both Xcode projects resolve (come up when clicked in the project navigator). ***Command-clicking a variable in code can't find the declaration that is literally 3 lines above.***

Stumped, ideas welcome.

(I'd show an example but SDK/ADK is covered under NDA)

Comment: Did you try to delete the derived data folder (or use a custom derived data location for the problematic project)?

Comment: I deleted the derived data folder and deleted the Xcode cache files. No effect.

Answer (score 0):

"what's really going to bake your noodle"...  *Xcode project indexing breaks if the project file (only the project file) is on a file server volume and not a local storage volume.*

As part of the clean up process, I had created the new project folder on my server.  Everything cleaned up nicely, but then as the question noted, Xcode refused to index the source code via the project file.

In diagnosing this, I made a full copy of the new cleaned up project on an external drive from the file server. When I opened up the project, everything looked normal and by accident I discovered the indexing was working.

SO, I opened the Xcode project file on the file server, made all the file locations "Absolute" and recompiled.  No indexing.  THEN I moved only the project file to my desktop and opened it.  It indexed perfectly. Moving the project file back to the file server and the indexing fails again.

Comment: Editorial: Xcode basics are very buggy and it has never been able to handle the file system well (can't use aliases, breaks on sim-links) so breaking with a file server is just par for the course.